# uitableview cell can't remove some constraints

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    //    ChoiceArticleCell *cell = (ChoiceArticleCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[ChoiceArticleCell reuseIdentifier] forIndexPath:indexPath];
        ChoiceArticleCell *cell = (ChoiceArticleCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[ChoiceArticleCell reuseIdentifier] ];
        NSLog(@"dequed cell.image:%@",cell.listMode.imgUrl);
        for (NSLayoutConstraint* constraint in cell.contentView.constraints)
        {
            NSLog(@"constraints:%@",constraint);
            
        }
        ArticleListModel *articleListModel = [_choiceArticles.articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell configWith:articleListModel];
        
        NSLog(@"after set cell.image:%@",articleListModel.imgUrl);
        for (NSLayoutConstraint* constraint in cell.contentView.constraints)
        {
            NSLog(@"constraints:%@",constraint);
    
        }
        return cell;
    }
```

[image]

the cell  remove or add the constraint dynamically .

but now when the view appears ,it always conplains my inequal constraints still exists and cause the  conflict,but during my logs in cellForRowAtIndexPath, i just create a cell without this inequal constraint , and i don't know why this constraint will be added again to the cell's contentView

in the console logs

```
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-01-08 15:13:40.547 iKM[10241:4003803] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18953210 V:[UIImageView:0x18896cc0]-(20)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x18897760 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18953180 V:|-(>=68)-[UIImageView:0x18896cc0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x18897760 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18963f40 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x18897760(82)]>"
)
```

i can see that in unequal constraint cause conflict is 0x18953180,but when i check the logs of creating cell , i have remove the 0x18953180 constraint after i set the cell's content

```
2016-01-08 15:13:40.436 iKM[10241:4003803] dequed cell.image:(null)
2016-01-08 15:13:40.437 iKM[10241:4003803] constraints:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x189530f0 H:|-(10)-[UILabel:0x18896eb0'文章标题文章标题文章标题']   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x18897760 )>
2016-01-08 15:13:40.437 iKM[10241:4003803] constraints:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18953120 V:|-(20)-[UILabel:0x18896eb0'文章标题文章标题文章标题']   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x18897760 )>
2016-01-08 15:13:40.437 iKM[10241:4003803] constraints:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18953150 H:[UILabel:0x18896eb0'文章标题文章标题文章标题']-(105)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x18897760 )>
2016-01-08 15:13:40.437 iKM[10241:4003803] constraints:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18953180 V:|-(>=68)-[UIImageView:0x18896cc0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x18897760 )>
2016-01-08 15:13:40.437 iKM[10241:4003803] constraints:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x189531b0 V:[UILabel:0x18896eb0'文章标题文章标题文章标题']-(>=10)-[UIImageView:0x18896cc0]>
2016-01-08 15:13:40.437 iKM[10241:4003803] constraints:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x189531e0 H:|-(10)-[UIImageView:0x18896cc0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x18897760 )>
2016-01-08 15:13:40.437 iKM[10241:4003803] constraints:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18953210 V:[UIImageView:0x18896cc0]-(20)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x18897760 )>
2016-01-08 15:13:40.438 iKM[10241:4003803] constraints:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18953240 UILabel:0x18897210'1542次浏览'.centerY == UILabel:0x18896a90'根据标签推荐#微信#'.centerY>
2016-01-08 15:13:40.438 iKM[10241:4003803] constraints:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18951970 UILabel:0x18897210'1542次浏览'.centerY == UIImageView:0x18896cc0.centerY>
2016-01-08 15:13:40.438 iKM[10241:4003803] constraints:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x189519a0 H:|-(25)-[UILabel:0x18897210'1542次浏览']   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x18897760 )>
2016-01-08 15:13:40.438 iKM[10241:4003803] constraints:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x189519d0 UILabel:0x18896830'2015'.centerY == UILabel:0x18897210'1542次浏览'.centerY>
2016-01-08 15:13:40.438 iKM[10241:4003803] constraints:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18951a00 H:[UILabel:0x18896830'2015']-(31)-[UIImageView:0x18952ef0]>
2016-01-08 15:13:40.438 iKM[10241:4003803] constraints:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18951a30 V:|-(20)-[UIImageView:0x18952ef0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x18897760 )>
2016-01-08 15:13:40.439 iKM[10241:4003803] constraints:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18951a60 H:[UIImageView:0x18952ef0]-(10)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x18897760 )>
2016-01-08 15:13:40.439 iKM[10241:4003803] constraints:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18951a90 H:[UILabel:0x18896a90'根据标签推荐#微信#']-(10)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x18897760 )>
2016-01-08 15:13:40.440 iKM[10241:4003803] after set cell.image:
2016-01-08 15:13:40.440 iKM[10241:4003803] constraints:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x189530f0 H:|-(10)-[UILabel:0x18896eb0'VR 会是下一个改变世界的计算平台吗？']   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x18897760 )>
2016-01-08 15:13:40.441 iKM[10241:4003803] constraints:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18953120 V:|-(20)-[UILabel:0x18896eb0'VR 会是下一个改变世界的计算平台吗？']   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x18897760 )>
2016-01-08 15:13:40.441 iKM[10241:4003803] constraints:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18953150 H:[UILabel:0x18896eb0'VR 会是下一个改变世界的计算平台吗？']-(10)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x18897760 )>
2016-01-08 15:13:40.441 iKM[10241:4003803] constraints:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x189531b0 V:[UILabel:0x18896eb0'VR 会是下一个改变世界的计算平台吗？']-(>=10)-[UIImageView:0x18896cc0]>
2016-01-08 15:13:40.441 iKM[10241:4003803] constraints:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x189531e0 H:|-(10)-[UIImageView:0x18896cc0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x18897760 )>
2016-01-08 15:13:40.441 iKM[10241:4003803] constraints:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18953210 V:[UIImageView:0x18896cc0]-(20)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x18897760 )>
2016-01-08 15:13:40.441 iKM[10241:4003803] constraints:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18953240 UILabel:0x18897210'59次浏览'.centerY == UILabel:0x18896a90'8分钟前'.centerY>
2016-01-08 15:13:40.442 iKM[10241:4003803] constraints:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18951970 UILabel:0x18897210'59次浏览'.centerY == UIImageView:0x18896cc0.centerY>
2016-01-08 15:13:40.442 iKM[10241:4003803] constraints:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x189519a0 H:|-(10)-[UILabel:0x18897210'59次浏览']   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x18897760 )>
2016-01-08 15:13:40.442 iKM[10241:4003803] constraints:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x189519d0 UILabel:0x18896830'2015'.centerY == UILabel:0x18897210'59次浏览'.centerY>
2016-01-08 15:13:40.442 iKM[10241:4003803] constraints:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18951a00 H:[UILabel:0x18896830'2015']-(31)-[UIImageView:0x18952ef0]>
2016-01-08 15:13:40.442 iKM[10241:4003803] constraints:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18951a30 V:|-(20)-[UIImageView:0x18952ef0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x18897760 )>
2016-01-08 15:13:40.443 iKM[10241:4003803] constraints:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18951a60 H:[UIImageView:0x18952ef0]-(10)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x18897760 )>
2016-01-08 15:13:40.443 iKM[10241:4003803] constraints:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18951a90 H:[UILabel:0x18896a90'8分钟前']-(10)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x18897760 )>
```

it's clearly that the 0x18953180 is exist after dequeued from tableView , and removed before return the cell to the tableView .  .

but this constraint be added to cell again , and i am sure is not my code added it again , what's the reason

Comment: what about using `[self layoutIfNeeded];` ?

Answer (score 0):

finally ,i found why there got the conflict , in fact , is the way i using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier , i should use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath , and rewrite the cell's prepareForReuse method ,in the prepareForReuse , i should remove the constraints first .

the inner reason why conflict happened , is when use deque cell , the dequed cell may contained some constraints (old constraints) of the old cell , and because the **cell's height is decided by the constraints of new cell(new constraints)** , so this may make conflicts happen (old constraints and new cell height)